# One C file invoking and running another c file in linux

Tags: c, linux

I have three c files one.c, two.c and three.c on Linux in same folder
I need to first run one.c file and then as soon as it completes running it should automatically run two.c file.
After two.c file completes running it should automatically run three.c and so on...

All the files will be compiled.

Thanks in advance !!! !! !

Comment: You probably must use (ba)sh for this, not C.

Comment: Just to be clear, one doesn't really execute a `.c` file. The `.c` file is compiled and then the binary executable is run. Can't you just compile `one.c`, `two.c`, and `three.c` and then put `one ; two ; three` in a script? Not sure what special behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile and run them separately, like jightuse and mbratch suggest in the comments.
Another approach to "running" each one, would be to link them together and run a function from each. Here, I've changed main() to main1(), main2(), and main3(), but in separate files.

```
poly@blue-starling ~/junk/2013.11: cat one.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main1(void)
{
  printf("one here!\n");
}

poly@blue-starling ~/junk/2013.11: cat two.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main2(void)
{
  printf("two here!\n");
}

poly@blue-starling ~/junk/2013.11: cat three.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main3(void)
{
  printf("three here!\n");
}

poly@blue-starling ~/junk/2013.11: cat main.c
void main(void)
{
    main1();
    main2();
    main3();
}

poly@blue-starling ~/junk/2013.11: gcc *.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:2: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’

poly@blue-starling ~/junk/2013.11: a.out
one here!
two here!
three here!
poly@blue-starling ~/junk/2013.11:
```

(It's broken some rules and gotten a warning, since the `main()` isn't strictly a proper main, but hopefully shows the idea.)

Anyway, that's one way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use a beginner's reference, such as [this one](http://www.karunya.edu/linuxclub/resources/GCC.pdf).

[This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) doesn't hurt either.

Both of them are small books, but it's best to go to the source when starting out.

Best of luck!